# How to open a Word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop including the mail merge datasource?

Tags: c#, office-interop, cpu-word

I have a Word document with a manually attached Excel-file as data source for mail merge.

When I open the document with a C#-script by using `Documents.Open()`, the document is opened but the data source is not linked anymore.

Is there a solution for opening (and saving) the document with the link still intact?

Comment: Why do you think the data source is not linked when a document is opened programmatically?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev thanks for commenting! I have the document in visible mode so I can see that the excel sheet is not linked anymore when the document is opened. Also when I let the program proceed and save the document the link is gone when I open the document manually afterwards.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others may replicate the issue.